# Solving a Nonlinear equation with Julia

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, julia

I am trying to solve a nonlinear equation with Julia,

I have the following nonlinear equation

```
Nfoc(k,k1,z,n)=(1-α)*exp(z)*(k/n)^α/(exp(z)*(k^α)*(n^(1-α))+k*(1-δ)-k1) - A/(1-n)
```

and I have a grid of values for k,k1 and z and I am trying to find the values of x that are the roots of this equation for each k,k1, and z, by using this loop:

```
MatrixN=zeros(nkk,M,nkk)

for i=1:nkk,j=1:M

  for i2=1:nkk
    MatrixN[i,j,i2]=roots(Nfoc[K[i],K[i2],z(j),n])
  end
end
```

However, its obvious that the command roots its not functioning.

Comment: Why is it obvious that `roots` is not working?

Comment: Because the code is not running hahaha

Comment: Looks like Reza figured this one out, but you'll generally get better answers if you explain what you expected and include specifically what happened instead, rather than just saying "it doesn't work". Remember to accept his answer!

Comment: @StefanKarpinsky do you know how to make Reza's suggestion go faster?

Comment: Nope. Root finding isn't really my area of expertise.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough knowledge to work on your use case, but in general, one way to find roots of a parametric function could be:

```
using FastAnonymous # Creating efficient "anonymous functions" in Julia
using Roots
f(x,k,k1,z,n) = exp(x) - x^4 + k + k1 + z + n
function f_gen(k,k1,z,n)
    @anon x -> f(x,k,k1,z,n) 
end
fzero(f_gen(0,0,0,0), 1) # => finds x so f(x,0,0,0,0) = 0 using a derivative free method
```

Comment: Reza it is taking me more than a day to run it. Do you know how to make it faster?

Comment: from my own experience in zero finding, selection of right algorithm and suitable starting point is very important. e.g some times each root could be initial point for finding the next one. higher order algorithms are faster. using analytic differentiation in some algorithm are remitted.